# How to add GPS coordinates instead of address in new Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts, geolocation

**tl;dr**: *How to add GPS location instead of address in new Google Contacts using PC computer? It seems to be possible only using mobile version (Contacts in Android)*.

---

I'd like to add a GPS coords instead of street address to one of my contacts in new Google Contacts (on my PC), because location of my friend's home is in such wilderness that it doesn't have street name or number. And there is no way to locate exact location of a home using any kind of postal / street number (Google Maps finds only village, about 5 km in incorrect direction.

Which field should I use in address box or how to switch street fields into GPS coordinates when adding new address block?

When I am trying to paste it in any of address block's fields it allows me to save such a block (from time to time, sometimes "Save" button remains disabled), but when I click such entry in contact's summary, it always adds a default (current) country code and instead of:

```
45.150844, 35.737150
```

which [works just fine](https://www.google.pl/maps/place/45%C2%B009'03.0%22N+35%C2%B044'13.7%22E/@45.1508478,35.7349613,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d45.150844!4d35.73715?hl=en) in Google Maps, it opens GM with:

```
45.150844, 35.737150, UA
```

instead -- which address / location [is not valid](https://www.google.pl/maps/search/45.150844,+35.737150,+UA/@45.1508478,35.7349613,17z?hl=en):

[image]

How can I add GPS coordinates in a reproducible way, so clicking corresponding entry in contact's summary would actually show me a valid, real location instead of error message?

Comment: looks like not possible either coz GC always appends country code to it which will invalidate the link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [plus code](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7047426?hl=en) of the location as the address, while still filling in the city and the country.

Answer (score -2):

only with a mobile App you can manually remove the country Code, e. g. UA and it works with Google maps. Not with a browser on a PC.
Claudius